# A question on connectedness

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I was going through a basic problem book in algebraic geometry. There in the very first chapter I have encountered a problem which asks to prove that hyperbolas are connected in $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$.

I was thinking to show that the corresponding ideal is prime and hence the variety is irreducible and hence connected (but that is just an idea which I think will be a tedious one  to implement, so I am searching for a simple way to prove it which may be purely topological).

Any help from any end is welcome.

Comment: The topological definition of connectedness is that a space is connected if there does not exist a pair of disjoint open sets whose union is the entire space. Provided you understand the nature of the topology on the space in question well enough, it is often not difficult to ascertain if the space is connected or not.

Comment: Here's a hint, following your idea. Let's say your hyperbola was given by the equation $xy = 1$. Then, the coordinate ring is $$\frac{\mathbf{C}[x,y]}{\langle 1-xy \rangle}$$ and you can figure out whether this is a domain or not.